# Parse script output from shell wanted in JScript

Tags: command-line, activexobject, jscript

I want to execute a command and parse the output from the shell. I am using JScript inside TestComplete. I already found out that I can run commands using WScript.shell. But I do not know how to parse the output in my JScript. Any hints?

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
if (shell)
{
  shell.run("myCommandIWantToParseOutputfrom.sh");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`Exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28VS.84%29.aspx) method instead of `Run`.

```js
var wsh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var cmd = wsh.Exec("cmd /c dir C:\ /on");

while (cmd.Status === 0) {
    WScript.Sleep(100);
}

var output = cmd.StdOut.ReadAll();
WScript.Echo(output);
```